# Perl Replace a value in a multidimentional hash reference

Tags: perl

I'm having a little difficulty replacing a value in a multidimentional hash reference.

```
while (  my ( $module, $default_parameters )   = each %{ $device_description_defaults } ) {
    while ( my ( $def_key, $def_value )   = each %{ $default_parameters } ) {
      if ( $def_key eq 'server' ) {
           $device_description_defaults->{$default_parameters}->{$def_key} = $device_servers->{$def_value}->{ $hostname->{'device_cluster'} };
      }
    }
}
```

results in an output of:

```
      'HASH(0xaa5fdc8)' => {
                             'server' => [
                                           '10.1.1.1',
                                           '10.1.1.2',
                                         ]
                           },
```

'HASH(0xaa5fdc8)' is supposed to be 'some_specific_string'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very unclear.

You seem to be using `Data::Dumper`, that's a good tool. Dump the structure of both hashes and things will hopefully become more clear.

No matter what were you doing, your output (of what?) tells us you used a hash reference as a hash key. Hash keys are always strings, so all scalars that you use as hash keys become strings, and strings like 'HASH(0xaa5fdc8)' is exactly what you get when you cast a hashref to a string in perl.

Comment: You are right. I realised I should have included the entire loop. After debugging a little more and replacing $default_parameters with a specific value I have narrowed the issue down. Basically $default_parameters is a HASH pointer but I am usng it as a string.

Comment: Replacing $default_parameters  with $module did the trick. $default_parameters  is a hash reference, $module is a string, what i needed

Answer (score 1):

```
$device_description_defaults->{$default_parameters}->{$def_key}
```

should be your choice of

```
$device_description_defaults->{$module}->{$def_key}
```

or

```
$default_parameters->{$def_key}
```

(I'd use the latter to be consistent with the `each` that returned `$def_key`.)